# Trouble when using Datatable.WriteXml to serialize enums

Tags: c#, xml, enums, datatable

I tried to write some data in a DataTable to a xml file using DataTable.WriteXml, the following code is an simplified version of what I actually used:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dt = new DataTable("TestDataTable");
    dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("PK", typeof(string))
    };
    dt.Columns.Add("Data1", typeof(double));
    dt.Columns.Add("Data2", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Data3", typeof(object));

    var r1 = dt.NewRow();
    r1["PK"] = "a";
    r1["Data1"] = 100.0;
    r1["Data2"] = 20;
    r1["Data3"] = TestEnum.TestValue1;
    dt.Rows.Add(r1);
    r1.Delete();

    var r2 = dt.NewRow();
    r2["PK"] = "b";
    r2["Data1"] = 200.0;
    r2["Data2"] = 21;
    r2["Data3"] = TestEnum.TestValue2;
    dt.Rows.Add(r2);

    var r3 = dt.NewRow();
    r3["PK"] = "c";
    r3["Data1"] = 300.0;
    r3["Data2"] = 22;
    r3["Data3"] = TestEnum.TestValue3;
    dt.Rows.Add(r3);

    var r4 = dt.NewRow();
    r4["PK"] = "d";
    r4["Data1"] = 400.0;
    r4["Data2"] = 23;
    r4["Data3"] = TestEnum.TestValue4;
    dt.Rows.Add(r4);
    r4.Delete();


    dt.WriteXml(@"E:\testenum.xml");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    TestValue1,
    TestValue2,
    TestValue3,
    TestValue4
}
```

However, the xml file it generates can't be read using DataTable.ReadXml and a DataException is thrown saying that a undefined data type "" causes the exception. The following is the output file testenum.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <TestDataTable>
    <PK>b</PK>
    <Data1>200</Data1>
    <Data2>21</Data2>
    <Data3 xsi:type="xs:" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1</Data3>
  </TestDataTable>
  <TestDataTable>
    <PK>c</PK>
    <Data1>300</Data1>
    <Data2>22</Data2>
    <Data3 xsi:type="xs:" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2</Data3>
  </TestDataTable>
</DocumentElement>
```

It seems that the attribute 'xsi:type' of element 'Data3' is incomplete, and that causes the problem. So I come to ask that anyone knows a solution to this problem?

Comment: You can cast an enumeration to an integer or a string (which gives the name of the enumeration) ; (int)TestEnum.TestValue3;

Comment: If you cast the enumeration to a different type and save it using DataTable.WriteXml, then DataTable.ReadXml will deserialize it as the type it was cast to, and you will have to cast it back one by one. I solved this problem with XmlSerializer, but this just still feels unpleasent. I wonder why DataTable.WriteXml fails to do the trick?

Comment: Did you use the write schema option with WriteXml()?

Comment: I tried with XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, not working either :(

Comment: Then the columns in the DataTable aren't defined properly.  Look at the schema column definitions and see if they are correct.  Columns defined as number will remove the leading zeroes.  Where leading zeroes are important, the DataTable columns must be defined as strings.

Comment: Indeed, however in my project this column contains a varity of objects, not only enumerations of this type but also integers, doubles and other user-defined objects, so the when creating this column, I have to use typeof(object) as param. Thanks though!

Comment: Then use string instead of object to preserve the leading zeroes.  The other solution would be to add another column indicating type.  Using a number like integers will always loose leading zeroes.  You can use a format to add the leading zeroes back when displaying results.

Comment: Right. I think at least I can bypass this problem, thanks!